# fwupdmgr fails with "suitable port not found" error

Tags: 22.10, fwupd

I have a Lenovo T15 and fwupdmgr was working fine before. But now, it fails with the following error:

```
Devices with no available firmware updates: 
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • UEFI Device Firmware
 • USB2.1 Hub
 • USB3.0 5K Graphic Docking
 • Unifying Receiver
╔══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╗
║ Upgrade EM120R GL from EM120RGLAPR02A07M4G_10.010.10.010 to                  ║
║ EM120RGLAPR02A07M4G_20.020.20.020?                                           ║
╠══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╣
║ Firmware release EM120RGLAPR02A07M4G_20.020.20.020 packaged for LVFS.        ║
║                                                                              ║
║ This stable release :                                                        ║
║                                                                              ║
║ Firmware release EM120RGLAPR02A07M4G_20.020.20.020 packaged for LVFS.        ║
║                                                                              ║
║ This stable release fixes the following issues:                              ║
║                                                                              ║
║ • Performance improvements                                                   ║
║                                                                              ║
║ EM120R GL and all connected devices may not be usable while updating.        ║
╚══════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════╝

Perform operation? [Y|n]: 
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Downloading…             [***************************************]
Decompressing…           [***************************************]
Authenticating…          [***************************************]
Restarting device…       [                                       ]suitable port not found
```

Even after manually restarting the computer, the firware didn't update and I still have the same issue.

Comment: Same problem here on a P14s gen2. BTW, your System Firmware is not listed under "no available firmware upgrades". For me, the issue also blocked an update and I had to install it individually.